# How to combine/append mfcc features with rmse and fft using librosa in python 2.7

Tags: fft, python, mfcc

I have an audio file say myfile.wav

I trained a neural network based on fft features, and it is giving pretty good results for detecting particular classes of sounds.

I want to expand above experiment to include more sophisthicated features like MFCC along with simpler features like RMSEnergy and so on.

Using librosa,

I can compute mfcc as follows:

```
import librosa
y, sr = librosa.load('myfile.wav')
mfcc=librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr)
print mfcc.shape
(20,5911)
```

Similarly  I can compute rmse as follows:

```
myrmse = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y)
print myrmse.shape
(1,5911)
```

Q1.
***Is it valid if I transpose mfcc and the myrsme and combine the two using numpy.hstack ?***

say

```
t = mfcc.transpose()
t2 = myrmse.transpose()
```

So that I now have two arrays : one of size (5911,20) and another of size (5911,1)
and

```
t3 = numpy.hstack((t,t2))
```

***Q2.
If above operation is valid, how do I  append more features to t3 , Ex:  SNR , FFT  and other audio features.

I'm particularly interested in combining fft with mfcc.***

***END GOAL***
My plan is to have feature data like this :

```
feat_1  feat_2 ...feat_20  rmse  feat_21 ...feat_n  label  
val     val        val      val     val        val      x
val     val        val      val     val        val      x
val     val        val      val     val        val      y
val     val        val
```

feat_1 .. feat_20 are mfcc related features.
rmse is rms energy from librosa
feat_21 could be some other thing like fft or SNR.

I want to train a ANN and see which combination of features work best for detecting a particular class of sound. And conclude if mfcc's / fft's alone is sufficient for achieving this.

If this is not the right forum kindly direct me to the correct place.

Thank you.

Comment: It has the same length so just stack them into `21, 5911` vector. Anyway, RMS energy is pretty much the same as 0’th MFCC coefficient, so no point in using them both.

Comment: ok thanks, guess I need to read my theory properly and then jump into all these things.